# Inconsistency of Bayesian Premium

Tags: bayesian, expected-value, posterior

Given:

1. The amount of a claim, $X$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,\theta]$
2. The prior density of $\theta$ is $\pi(\theta) = \frac{500}{\theta^2}, \theta > 500$

Two claims, $x_1=400$ and $x_2=600$ are observed. The posterior distribution is
$$f(\theta|x_1,x_2)=3\bigg(\frac{600^3}{\theta^4}\bigg), \theta > 600$$
Calculate the Bayesian premium, $E(X_3|x_1,x_2)$

Why the resulted Bayesian premium is different under these two methods:

1. Calculate the posterior distribution of $X_3$, I will get $X_3|x_1,x_2$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,800]$ hence,  $E(X_3|x_1,x_2)=400$
2. Using the formula $\int_{600}^\infty E[X_3|\theta] f(\theta|x_1,x_2) d\theta$ i will get $E(X_3|x_1,x_2)=450$

Comment: For the first method:
$f(X_3|x_1,x_2)=\int_{600}^\infty  \frac{1}{\theta} 3\bigg(\frac{600^3}{\theta^4}\bigg) d\theta$

Will resulted in $f(X_3|x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{800}$
Hence $E[X_3|x_1,x_2]=400$
Note: I have checked that using the CDF, $X_3|x_1,x_2$ is indeed uniform $[0,800]$

Comment: For the second method: $\int_{600}^\infty E[X_3|\theta]f(\theta|x_1,x_2)d\theta=\int_{600}^\infty \frac{\theta}{2} 3\bigg(\frac{600^3}{\theta^4}\bigg) d\theta=450$

Comment: For those who are curious, the support in posterior of $\theta$ become $\theta>600$ since we observed $x_2=600$ and $x_2$ should be contained in interval $[0,\theta]$

Answer (score 5):

For the first method, it makes no conceptual sense that the posterior distribution should have bounded support. The observations that $x_1=400$ and $x_2=600$ allow you to rule out $\theta < 600$, but any value of $\theta > 600$ still is possible, so intuitively, the distribution of $X_3$ should have positive support for all values of $X_3$.

Now, turning to where your computation goes wrong, note that $f(X_3|\theta) = \frac1\theta\times 1\{X_3 \leq \theta\}$. In your calculation, you have forgotten the crucial $1\{X_3 \leq \theta\}$ piece. Including it, you should find that
$$f(X_3 | x_1,x_2) = 
\int_{\max(X_3,600)}^\infty\frac1\theta 3\left(\frac{600^3}{\theta^4}\right)\mathrm d\theta$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, the bayesian premium is now 450, same with the second method.

Comment: Appreciate your explanation of $X_3$ support